# extract parameters and r-squared from a subseted with sapply

Tags: r, sapply

To run a regresion by subset, I did as follows :

```
z1 <- sapply(  split( data , data$code), function(d){ dat <- list2env(d)
nlsfit <- nlsLM(form = SGP ~ a *exp(-b*exp(-c*time)), data=dat, start= list( a=30, b=1.5, c = 0.053)) 

list(summary(nlsfit))} )
```

I am able to see the parameters, that works well, however when I try to export them with `write.csv` all that I obtain is a weird and mixed sheet in excel

Instead of  `list(summary(nlsfit))`
I did try
`as.array.default`
`as.array` `as.table`
`as.data.frame`

And if I remove `summary` and write `coef` I get the coefficients nicely arranged in an excel file .csv, but nothing else (r-squared, Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|))

Thank you

I am subseting data by variable code, here I share part of it because code keeps growing up to 300_PI

The object data is:

````
structure(list(id = 1:300, code = c("1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", "1_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", "2_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", "3_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", "4_PI", 
                                    "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", 
                                    "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", 
                                    "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI", "5_PI"
), run = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
time = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 
         96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 
         2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 
         4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 
         6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
         8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
         12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 
         16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 
         24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 
         36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 
         48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 
         60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 
         72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 
         96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 
         2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 
         4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 
         6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
         8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
         12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 
         16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 
         24L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 
         36L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 
         48L, 60L, 72L, 96L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 36L, 48L, 
         60L, 72L, 96L), SGP = c(7.9, 9.9, 11.2, 13.3, 17.4, 21, 27, 
                                 32.8, 36.8, 38.4, 40, 41, 7.1, 8.7, 9.1, 11.7, 14.8, 18.7, 
                                 25, 30.9, 35.4, 36.8, 39, 40, 8.1, 10.4, 11.5, 14.2, 15.6, 
                                 19.1, 25.6, 29.6, 33.8, 35.2, 36.6, 37.6, 7.9, 12, 15, 17.3, 
                                 20.8, 23.3, 27.8, 31.4, 33.8, 35.4, 36.3, 37.6, 7.3, 10.8, 
                                 12.4, 16.5, 19.3, 22.5, 26.4, 29.4, 32.4, 34.8, 35.8, 38.2, 
                                 8.6, 10.3, 10.8, 13.4, 17.1, 21.6, 26.8, 32, 36, 37.4, 38.4, 
                                 39.4, 8.7, 11.1, 12, 14.3, 18.1, 21.7, 27.9, 32.8, 36.7, 
                                 37.6, 39.1, 39.5, 9.1, 10.8, 11.2, 13.8, 16.5, 20, 26.2, 
                                 30.8, 34.2, 35.6, 37.1, 37.9, 8.5, 13.4, 16.7, 17.5, 18.7, 
                                 20.8, 24.1, 26.3, 28.7, 30.4, 31.4, 32.5, 8.7, 13.2, 15.9, 
                                 18.3, 20.3, 22.5, 27, 29.7, 31.8, 33.5, 34.6, 36.2, 8.9, 
                                 13.2, 15.9, 18.2, 19.6, 21.9, 26.2, 28.7, 30.3, 32, 33, 34.6, 
                                 9.4, 12.3, 14, 15.9, 18.6, 21.6, 26.3, 31, 34.8, 36.2, 37.8, 
                                 39, 8.6, 11.2, 13, 15.8, 19.1, 22.1, 26.9, 31.2, 35.4, 36.1, 
                                 38.3, 38.9, 9.4, 11.7, 13.4, 16.4, 18.3, 21.6, 26.7, 30.9, 
                                 34.8, 36.2, 37.7, 37.9, 10.1, 13.7, 17.4, 20.2, 22.7, 24.4, 
                                 27.7, 29.1, 31.7, 32.6, 33.5, 34.5, 9.2, 13.3, 16.5, 19.8, 
                                 20.9, 22.9, 26.4, 28.2, 30, 31.8, 32.6, 34.5, 8.9, 12.9, 
                                 16.1, 19.5, 19.7, 20.8, 25, 26.9, 28.7, 30.7, 31.6, 32.5, 
                                 6.3, 8, 8, 12.8, 16.8, 20.8, 26.7, 32, 36.3, 36.9, 38.7, 
                                 40.1, 6.8, 8.2, 8.2, 10.8, 14, 17.7, 23.5, 28.4, 32.7, 34, 
                                 35.3, 36.2, 5.9, 7.9, 8.3, 11.6, 14.5, 18.3, 24.3, 28.6, 
                                 33, 34.1, 35.7, 36.5, 7.8, 12.3, 15.6, 17.4, 19.9, 21.5, 
                                 24.7, 27.3, 29.3, 31.1, 31.6, 33.1, 6.6, 10.3, 13, 16.1, 
                                 17.1, 19.8, 23, 24.3, 26.5, 27.9, 28.9, 30.3, 6.6, 10.2, 
                                 12.9, 15.4, 16.2, 19, 22.3, 24.6, 25.9, 27, 28, 29.4, 7.9, 
                                 10.3, 12.4, 15.6, 19.6, 22.9, 29.5, 34.7, 39, 39.9, 41.6, 
                                 42.6, 8.2, 11.5, 13.3, 16.2, 18, 21.4, 26.8, 30.9, 34.7, 
                                 35.6, 37.1, 36.8), dm = c(36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 36.44, 
                                                           36.44, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 
                                                           36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 
                                                           36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 
                                                           35.85, 35.85, 35.85, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 
                                                           38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 
                                                           38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49, 38.49
                                 )), row.names = c(NA, 300L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Can you share the object `data`?

Comment: Can you use the `broom` package?

Comment: Hi @Liman Sure I edited and added part of it.... Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ben, let me read about and try, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: OK @Vake, you should use `dput ()` to share your data. The data you posted can't be used without substantial pre-processing. As suggested by @Ben, you can use `broom` package. Here is a basic example based  on `lm` output:

`ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14);
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69);
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"));
weight <- c(ctl, trt);

lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)%>%
  broom::glance()
`

Comment: Oo I see, yeah makes a lot of sens, I edited my question and added the data on the right way (I think), I hope it helps to undestand what I mean, meanwhile I am exploring your second suggestion, thnks!

Comment: broom::glance() worked! thanks a lot!